# T-SQL CURSOR with blank output

Tags: t-sql

Working on SQL CURSOR and encounter blank output amongst right output. Check on pubs database and got the blank output too. Script for pubs

```
DECLARE @auid varchar(30)
DECLARE CURSOR_AuthorTitle CURSOR FOR
    SELECT au_id FROM authors order by au_lname
OPEN CURSOR_AuthorTitle
    FETCH NEXT FROM CURSOR_AuthorTitle INTO @auid 
    WHILE @@Fetch_Status = 0 
    BEGIN
        ;With authortitle_id as 
        (SELECT a.au_id, title_id, au_fname, au_lname, royaltyper 
        FROM authors a, titleauthor ta 
        WHERE a.au_id=ta.au_id) 

        SELECT 'Author Name' =  au_fname +' ' + au_lname, 'Book Title'= title 
        FROM authorTitle_id at, titles t 
        WHERE at.title_id=t.title_id and au_id=@auid   
        ORDER BY au_lname

    FETCH NEXT FROM CURSOR_AuthorTitle INTO @auid
    END
CLOSE CURSOR_AuthorTitle
DEALLOCATE CURSOR_AuthorTitle
```

Got the author & book list, but with some blank outputs as well.  I want to get rid of the blank output.  Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: FYI, your join syntax is from pre-1992, and you don't use table alias values on every column.  There is no need to use a cursor and/or a CTE with this, it should be a single query.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  I'm brand new to SQL and working on HW project.  What do you mean pre-1992? shall I specify inner join and are there any different?

Comment: when you comma separate tables in the `FROM` clause and put the join conditions in the `WHERE` clause you are using an outdated SQL standard.  you should use join syntax like `inner join .... ON ...`, `left outer join .... ON ....`, etc

Comment: What do you mean by *blank output*? Empty (as in "0-row") result sets? Or non-empty sets with empty (NULL?) contents?

Answer (score 2):

Watch out when you concatenate NULL values.  if you have blank columns it is because you have some NULL columns.  Remember that:

`'your string'+null` = `null`

try using ISNULL() like this:

`'your string'+ISNULL(null,'')` = `'your string'`

your code:

```
SELECT 'Author Name' =  au_fname +' ' + au_lname, 'Book Title'= title
```

should be:

```
SELECT 'Author Name' =  ISNULL(au_fname+' ','') + ISNULL(au_lname,'')
```

If you have blank rows, it is because you authors that do not have any titles.  I not sure why you don't just have a single query for this and forget the cursor.

Comment: Thanks KM.  I tried the ISNULL(), but it did not get rid of the blank output. It is fine if I just run the Select statement. Blank output is due to the use of CURSOR.